# Raphaël vs jsDraw2D

Tags: javascript, graphics

Soon I'll have to make a JS browser app, and for that I'll need to use some graphics library that will let me draw some objects/forms (squares, circles... nothing non-regular). I'll need to be able to apply "textures" (read as: set a background image for the shape) and handle events (click and drag).

I saw both [jsDraw2D](http://jsdraw2d.jsfiction.com/) and [Raphaël](http://raphaeljs.com/), and they both are good, but I don't what which one is .
Do you have any experience using some of those libraries? Or maybe some other? Which one do you recommend me?

Regards

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is the great review of three popular drawing libraries:

http://coding.smashingmagazine.com/2012/02/22/web-drawing-throwdown-paper-processing-raphael/